# Thread Safety in operations involving ConcurrentHashMap in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, synchronized

Context: I'm creating a new `Item`, caching it and returning it, however, its name must be unique. We're talking about multithreaded env. My questions are in the comments.

```
class ItemOperations {

    private ConcurrentMap<String, Item> store = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    Item createItem(String name) throws Exception {

        // I agree this operation is thread safe because of ConcurrentHashMap
        if (store.containsKey(name)) {
            throw new Exception("Already Exists");
        }

        // Item creation is Expensive operation
        Item newItem = new Item();
        // *Ques 1* : For above - multiple threads will create multiple different objects right ?


        // putIfAbsent is again thread safe due to concurrentMap..
        // Losing thread will not update the value.. (correct me if i'm wrong)
        store.putIfAbsent("newItemName", newItem);


        // *Ques 2* : Separate threads will return different objects and
        // the second thread will return a new object which is 
        //NOT present in the store but was created on the fly , hence returning incorrect data
        return newItem;
    }
}
```

How to fix this ?

My thoughts: Should the whole createItem() be wrapped in a synchronized(this) block? so that Item Object creation is thread safe ? If yes, we'll lose the benefits of ConcurrentHashmap and it'll further degrade performance.

Using put instead of putIfAbsent is worse - ensures data correctness, but useless multiple writes to hashmap - hence impacting performance.

Comment: Don't put your questions into the comments. You can see for yourself that they are almost invisible. Put them into the text part of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, your method is not threadsafe. Why?

It is possible for two thread invocations of this method to reach this line and see a missing key:

```
if (store.containsKey(name)) {
    throw new Exception("Already Exists");
 }
```

If both invocations see the name key as missing, then your item now gets created twice. So what's the lesson here? Using ConcurrentHashMap on its own is not enough, at least not in the way you are using it.

What you want to do is take advantage of ConcurrentHashMap's *atomic* methods. The answer posted by DuncG provides a way to do this:

```
return map.computeIfAbsent(name, () -> new Item());
```

Now, the ConcurrentHashMap takes care of the thread-safety for you, and you have no need of using the synchronized keyword. Effectively, it will check the map, create the object if it is missing, and return it, all atomically, without any concern for race conditions.

All that said, if your use case can tolerate two or more creations of the Item() and two or more versions floating around (by chance), then it may not be that big of a deal. That said, I'd still recommend going with the computeIfAbsent approach since it guarantees consistent behavior.

Comment: Sounds good for this case. But, if there are some other actions in the same method, which need to be Atomic/thread-protected (actions not on store , but some other variable/resources) , what do you suggest in that case?

Comment: @HyperVol It really depends considering that there's a vast world of multithreaded possibilities. I.e. What resource are you protecting/Why? Do the actions you describe need to be in the same method? Why? What do they need to be "synchronized" with?

Answer (score 2):

You are ignoring the return value of `putIfAbsent` which would allow you to return consistent values.

However you can replace most of the method by a single call to

```
return map.computeIfAbsent(name, key -> new Item());
```

Comment: That's correct , but putIfAbsent returns old value so i doubt it'll be useful here

Comment: @Hypervol Your logic is flawed as two threads can get past `store.containsKey(name)` as false, and both evaluate `putIfAbsent`. One putIfAbsent call will return null, and the other will return the `new Item()` of the other thread. Because you don't check, a different version of newItem gets returned by the "losing" caller. With `computeIfAbsent` there is never inconsistent return for same name.

Comment: @HyperVol That's correct, it returns the old value instead of putting the new value. How is that not useful?